# Angular (1.x) - Programmatically access NG-REPEAT from code

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to setup hotkeys for an old project that still uses angular 1.x and one of the features I was trying to add would be to select the first row from a table that is created with an `NG-REPEAT`. I've been able to add in other functionality such has moving the selected row up / down because I pass in the selected row on `ng-click="setSelected(this)"` which then lets me save the row and move it with `selectedRow.$$prevSibiling` or `selectedRow.$$nextSibiling`.

What I'm having a hard time figuring out is how can I set the `selectedRow` from the controller.

Here is a quick example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/6jPHlYwkgF5raRWt?open=lib%2Fscript.js

JS:

```
App.controller('ActivitiesCtrl', [function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.selectedRow = "Not set";
  vm.activities = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "code": "ABC",
      "person": "Joe"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "code": "DFF",
      "person": "Sally"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "code": "ABC",
      "person": "Sue"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "code": "124",
      "person": "Sam"
    },
  ];
  vm.setSelected = function(row) {
    vm.selectedRow.selected = false;
    vm.selectedRow = row;
    vm.selectedRow.selected = true;
  }
  vm.moveNext = function() {
    vm.setSelected(vm.selectedRow.$$nextSibling)
  }
  vm.setFirst = function() {
    vm.setSelected("How do I set it...");
    // How to set it? vm.setSelected(?????)
  }
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="ActivitiesCtrl as vm">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Code</th>
      <th>Person</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="activity in vm.activities track by activity.id" ng-click="vm.setSelected(this)" ng-class="{info: selected}">
        <td>{{activity.id}}</td>
        <td>{{activity.code}}</td>
        <td>{{activity.person}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
{{vm.selectedRow | json}}
<hr />
<button ng-click="vm.setFirst()">Set First</button>
<button ng-click="vm.moveNext()">Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You can look at the example on the below link.

https://ciphertrick.com/highlight-a-selected-row-in-ng-repeat-using-ng-class/

Comment: @ThomsonMixab I'm already doing that unless I missed something from that blog. What I want to do is to be able to select one of the rows *from outside* of the ng-repeat itself. Like my example has a button that would select the first item in the ng-repeat, but I have no idea how to get that object from outside of the ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting the actual object from the array as selectedRow rather than using `this` and set the class by checking if `selectedRow === activity` in the ng-class.

This approach doesn't require mutating the objects

```
<tr
    ng-repeat="activity in vm.activities track by activity.id"
    ng-click="vm.setSelected(activity)"
    ng-class="{info: vm.selectedRow == activity}"
>
```

Then you can use Array#findIndex() to get the current selectedRow index in the array and if a next one exists use it or go back to the first.

For the `setFirst()` you just use `vm.activities[0]`

```
vm.selectedRow = null;

vm.setSelected = function (row) {     
  vm.selectedRow = row;     
};

vm.moveNext = function () {
  const {selectedRow:curr, activities:act} = vm;
  if (curr !== null) {
    let idx = act.findIndex(e => e == curr) + 1;
    let next = act[idx] || act[0];        
    vm.setSelected(next);
  }      
};

vm.setFirst = function () {
  vm.setSelected(vm.activities[0]);
};
```

[Working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/f0rOyndwfqXYwLq2?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

Comment: Thanks that worked very well. I changed it to just ``indexOf(curr)`` instead of ``findIndex`` since we are using ES5 with typescript, but overall it got me on the right track and did solve the issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link with test working example.

```
enter code here 
http://plnkr.co/edit/7mTvRB0ZlHOQwOIc?preview
```

Comment: This breaks the "next" button since it can't work with the next/previous sibling objects anymore. Helps though :)